# Subtraction of alphanumeric values with PHP

Tags: php

I have some data which are alphanumeric values and my code is like this:

```
$Diff1 = $row['RALL1'] - $row['ALL1'];

echo "<tr>"; 
  echo "<td>". $Diff1 . "</td>"; 
echo "</tr>";
```

Here the RAll and All values are alphanumeric characters, and both start with a single letter "a", and proceeds with numbers. eg, a14, a5, a2 etc.

if the output of the above `$Diff1` is like this: `$Diff1 = a10 - a2`, 
how can I get the result of this subtraction with PHP? in this case it should be

```
$Diff1 = a10 - a2 = a8
```

Thanks.

Comment: in your RAll and All there is always `a` and after it contain numbers?

Comment: RAll1 and All1 contains only a single "a",  no other letters or spaces between them.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: There's no clear way how to do arithmetic with letters. You'll need to separate the numbers from the letters, do the subtraction, and put it back together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below code

```
//$Diff1 = $row['RALL1'] - $row['ALL1'];
$RALL1=ltrim($row['RALL1'],"a");
$ALL1=ltrim($row['ALL1'],"a");
$Diff1 = $RALL1 - $ALL1;
$Diff1="a".$Diff1;
echo "<tr>"; 
  echo "<td>". $Diff1 . "</td>"; 
echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: You are Welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the preceding letter can always be safely ignored you can do this:

```
$first = (int) preg_replace('/[^\d]/', '', $row['RALL1']);
$second = (int) preg_replace('/[^\d]/', '', $row['ALL']);

$Diff1 = 'a' . ($first - $second);
```

The `preg_replace` will filter out anything that is not a number from the row. Later we do the subtraction and prefix the result with a letter, here `a`.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake with the regex. I filtered out the numbers instead of the letters. Try the edited version.